# When apache restart, php background process are killed

Tags: php, apache, process, background, kill

I have an issue with apache and php.

I call this script in php:

```
exec("nohup sudo QUIET=y sh foo.sh > /home/tmp/log.txt 2>&1 & echo $!", $res);
```

Shortly after, the script foo.sh need to restart apache to include new configuration files:

```
/etc/init.d/apachectl restart
```

In command line, it works fine but in my php script the process is killed at the same time apache is restarted. Why? I thought nohup detach the processus of its parent.

(I point out that i can't change the sh script)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `/etc/init.d/apachectl reload` instead?

Comment: nohup doesn't detach it from its parent, it just keeps it from being closed down when the terminal session ends (hangs up, "hup")

Comment: I can't change the sh script (it belongs to the company), sorry :/

Comment: Apache's signals support and how it reacts are documented here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html. HUP kills all the children but does not restart the original parent.

Comment: If nohup doesn't detach from its parent, would you know an other command ?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `/etc/init.d/apachectl reload` if the only thing you want is to reread configuration files.

Comment: I can't change the sh script (it belongs to the company), sorry :/, any other ideas?

Comment: @user1883264 If you cannot change the Shell script, because it belongs to the company.. And yo are on a project which actively uses this; then either submit a request the edit this file to your manager OR create a copy of this shell; give it a different name and change as you need

Answer (score 1):

```
/etc/init.d/apachectl reload
```

This will not `stop` the service, but keep it running and refreshes the processes configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/etc/init.d/apachectl reload` instead if you dont want to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Since `apache restart` sends SIGTERM, not SIGHUP,
you should handle SIGTERM from `foo.sh`